# Node how to make socket only accept local connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

What's the best practise to do it by node itself, not by firewall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [server.listen](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback), you can pass a `host` to limit the the range of accepted IP addreses:

`server.listen(1234, '127.0.0.1');`